# Not able to execute rundeck cli commands

Tags: rundeck

I installed rundeck cli and created .rd directory and configured rd.conf as below

```
export RD_URL=https://rundeck.url:4440
export RD_TOKEN=rundecktoken
export RD_DEBUG=1
```

when I try to hit some cli commands, its giving following error...

```
# Including extension: org.rundeck.client.tool.commands.repository.Plugins
# Including extension: org.rundeck.client.tool.commands.enterprise.license.License
# Including extension: org.rundeck.client.tool.commands.enterprise.cluster.Cluster
# Including extension: org.rundeck.client.ext.acl.Acl
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.kt:128)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.kt:295)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:207)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at org.rundeck.client.util.StaticHeaderInterceptor.intercept(StaticHeaderInterceptor.java:38)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at org.rundeck.client.util.StaticHeaderInterceptor.intercept(StaticHeaderInterceptor.java:38)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:204)
        at org.rundeck.client.util.Client.checkErrorDowngradable(Client.java:166)
        at org.rundeck.client.util.Client.apiCallDowngradable(Client.java:606)
        at org.rundeck.client.tool.commands.RdToolImpl.apiCallDowngradable(RdToolImpl.java:107)
        at org.rundeck.client.tool.commands.RdToolImpl.apiCall(RdToolImpl.java:78)
        at org.rundeck.client.tool.extension.BaseCommand.apiCall(BaseCommand.java:24)
        at org.rundeck.client.tool.commands.Executions.list(Executions.java:264)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1972)
        at picocli.CommandLine.access$1300(CommandLine.java:145)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2358)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2352)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2314)
        at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2179)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2316)
        at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2078)
        at org.rundeck.client.tool.Main.main(Main.java:155)
        Suppressed: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
                ... 47 more
```

when i try to make curl request to this https url, its giving connection timed out error...
can any one help me on this?

Comment: Hi, more context is needed: which RD CLI version are you using? Which Rundeck version are you trying to access? Can you access the Rundeck instance via web? Which error are you seeing after the Curl request? Is the Rundeck instance behind a proxy server? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, my RD CLI version is `2.0.3` . My rundeck version is `Rundeck 2.6.9-1 `. Its running on EC2 and I am able to browse UI. I configured HTTPS with AWS App Load Balancer. When I try to make curl request, this is the error what I get: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to rundeckurl 4440: Connection timed out`

Comment: That's a connectivity problem, to configure RD CLI against a "proxied" Rundeck instance please take a look at this: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/rd-cli/configuration.html#bypass-an-external-url You are using a Rundeck instance URL, not the Proxy Rundeck URL.

Comment: I added `export RD_BYPASS_URL`. Even then it is giving failed to connect:connection time out error. Can you show me how my rd.conf look like? thanks...

Comment: Its working now. Its not giving connection time out error. I modified my security group rules under AWS App Load Balancer. Then I could able to make api calls also. thanks..

Comment: Great! Please add your answer and mark it.